# Is it possible to have a chrome extension on android chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I've been searching but all I can find is a reference to download another browser called yandex and install the chrome extensions I have on that.

I want to create an app that uses a chrome extension in android to allow the user to download images and store them in a folder.

E.g. My app: the user will search google images and each image that the user views, an icon will appear top right on the image which provides the user with a menu to download to a specific folder.

But the only extensions I've been able to download are for desktop.

Can I achieve what I want with my app?

Comment: have you seen this feature anywhere?

Comment: The feature i want to invoke in my app? Yes. It was an old chrome extension program that displayed an icon above each image in google search.

Comment: But i dont know if it works on android or if its doable

Comment: I don't think you can do that